# certbot modifies the default nginx config

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, certbot

I am following a mini-tutorial to install letsencrypt certificates. OS is ubuntu 22.04.

I had already installed nginx, and my own example.com config file to /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
```

I left the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default unchanged.

I removed the pre-installed certbot

```
sudo apt remove certbot
```

Then I installed snap and classic certbot:

```
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
sudo snap install --classic certbot
sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

Then I ran

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Then I did

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com
```

I accept the agreement, entered my email, and hit return.

Instead of modifying /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com, /etc/nginx/sites-available/default was modified.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No solution found

Comment: It happened to me when I forgot to create symlink to /sites-enabled folder before running the certbot. Steps I took:
1- created symlink to sites-enabled folder
2- removed certbot related stuff from default config file
3- restarted nginx service
4- deployed the certificate again and it worked